# creating textbox onfly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div to update say `div id="txtbx"`. I need to insert  textboxes inside this div. But the textbox should be equal to the no of the checkboxes in my page. So I am looping the checkbox as

```
$("#checkboxid").find("input[type=checkbox]").each (function(index)
{
    //code to insert textboxes
});
```

But I am not sure how to insert these textboxes for each  checkboxes. I tried using `append().`, but it will not update that `div(txtbx)` rather it will append the textboxes.

Comment: It might be a good idea if you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ as what you are trying to do isn't too hard, but I can't figure out what you are doing right now.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than loop through each checkbox, you should count them first:

```
var num_boxes = $('#checkboxid').find('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
for(var i = 0; i < num_boxes; i++)
{
    var this_box = $('<input type="text" name="textbox_' + i + '" />');
    $('#txtbx').append(this_box);
}
```

Comment: Rather than appending it, is there any way to insert html. like var input_html=html+<input type="text">.. So this variable html would be an array of input tag html and then insert it into the div id as ('#txtbx').html(input_html);

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that? The variable would not be an array of `input` element HTML markup - it would simply be a concatenated string of HTML. Can you explain why you think you need to use this method, rather than `append()`?

Comment: Yes.. what i need is a concatenated string of html. Because when used append each time my checkbox is dropped, then it would append these  textboxes into that div. Rather I need to update that div.

Comment: You really need to put together a jsFiddle as Dave has suggested above in the comments. Using `append()` should have no affect on the checkboxes...

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$('#checkboxid').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index)
{
    var text_box = $('<input>', { type : "text", name="textbox_"+index});
    $('#txtbx').append(text_box);
});
```

also note that you must use the same comma type here

```
$('#checkboxid")
```